# Can an improper jump start cause damage to the starter motor?

Tags: battery

Can a charger pack applied to the wrong terminals cause damage to a starter motor on a car. This was done resulting in a loud bang, flash and smoke inside the vehicle. What other damage could have been caused.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose it could damage the starter, but it's more likely that you're going to have issues with all the onboard electronics.  Modern cars are full of mini computer systems that don't like improper voltage.  With smoke coming out, something has certainly blown up, and the car needs a thorough going over by someone that's an automotive electrical expert.

Answer (score 0):

it can harm the alternator. By accidently touching positive to negative when appplying the cables you can cause a short in the system and do damage.